# SKlearn's KFold generates NaN values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a feature frame with just 1 column, named `X` which contains float values and a label vector `y` with binary classes (1 or 0).

When I do `X.isnull().sum()`, it outputs `0` and same is the case with the label vector. But when I try to index `X` inside the KFold loop like this:

```
acc = []
for train_ind, test_ind in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_ind], X[test_ind]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_ind], y[test_ind]

    dtree.fit(X_train, y_train)
    acc.append(accuracy_score(y_test, dtree.predict(X_test)))
    print(acc)
print(np.array(acc).mean())
```

it outputs an error saying `Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').`
and when I do `X_train.insull().sum()`, it outputs 2. That means it is generating 2 nan values on indexing. Is my indexing correct for the feature and label vectors?

Comment: Which version of scikit are you using? Please post the full stack trace. Is X a pandas object or numpy object?

Comment: I'm using sklearn 0.18. I extracted X by doing `X = df['sim']` so i think X is a pandas object.

Comment: Ok. Then you should print the train_ind and test_ind to verify your doubts. On which step from above posted do you get the error.?

Comment: it returns an error on `dt.train(X_train, y_train)` due to NaN in the input. And yes i tried printing `X_train`. It contains additional 2 NaN as mentioned in the question as well.

Comment: Well, then print the full code (along with the initialization of KFold) which is causing the error and the full stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the case but I believe some indices are missing in y dataframe. Try resetting it before running the loop:

```
y.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

According to what @Utkarsh Sah mentioned, the problem is some missing indices in y data frame. Reset the indices before using the y dataframe:

```
y=y.reset_index(drop=True)
```